# Intermec PM4i ASCII symbol print

Tags: intermec

Does anybody know how to print specific symbol with Intermec PM4i printer? I need to print degree symbol (°). Here is my code:

```
  <STX>H1;o20,10;w1;h2;f0;c2;d3,DEGREE° ;<ETX>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the script syntax you use, I have used Intermec-DP(Direct Protocol) command syntax. Installed Generic text driver, USB cable connection to PM4i. I did not use Intermec printer driver 'cause was having problems with it.

Use Notepad to print this script. NASC 1252 chooses Windows-1252 character map, CHR$(xx) escapes any character you want. Try chr(176).

```
INPUT ON
NASC 1252
PP 30,540 
FT "Swiss 721 Bold BT",8,0,100
PT "My label ÅÄÖ 12#";CHR$(34);" is hot 100 ";CHR$(176);" degrees"
PF
```